# Bokeh plot update in notebook but not in static HTML

Tags: python, html, css, django, bokeh

This is the first time to ask a question here . I'm totally new to HTML , CSS , JavaScipt , Django , Python and Bokeh . I'm poor in English . And I'll appreciate for your help .

I'm meeting a problem when I want to realize a simple function . There is 2 plots here . When I click the circle of the first plot , the circles not associated with in the second spot will be hidden . It's work in notebook . But when I add it into an HTML page . The second plot won't Change . I use Django+python to realize this function . And I use HTML component tag to add plots into an web page.

I'm sorry that I'm not allow to put a picture here, but there are links.

Here is the gif when it works in notebook .
[work in notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXjyh.gif)

And this is the gif when it's not work in static HTML .
[not work in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npb9D.gif)

Here is the HTML code .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
    <link
    href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.13.0.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.13.0.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.13.0.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.13.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
{{ script2 |safe }}
{{ div2 |safe }}
{{ script3 |safe }}
{{ div3 |safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the python code .

```html
from PIL.ImageQt import rgb
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox, layout
from bokeh.models import Range1d, Title, Label, PrintfTickFormatter, NumeralTickFormatter, Axis, ColumnDataSource, \
    ColorBar, LinearAxis, TapTool, CDSView, BooleanFilter, CustomJS, Slider, layouts, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure, Figure
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.layouts import column
# Create your views here.
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap
from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):

    data1 = {'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
             'projectname': ["project1", "project2", "project3", "project4", "project5", "project6", "project7"],
             'id': ['byq-1', 'byq-2', 'byq-3', 'byq-4', 'byq-5', 'byq-6', 'byq-7'],
             'missingnumber0': [1, 2, 30, 22, 23, 5, 9],
             'missingnumber1': [3, 4, 30, 12, 20, 1, 20],
             'missingnumber': [4, 6, 60, 34, 43, 6, 29],
             'holi': [0.10, -0.20, 0.30, -0.11, -0.32, 0.44, 0.05],
             'lilo': [0.23, -0.21, 0.02, 0.03, 0.66, 0.31, 0.22],
             'holo': [0.33, -0.41, 0.32, -0.08, 0.34, 0.75, 0.27],
             }
    data2 = data1
    source1 = ColumnDataSource(data1)
    source2 = ColumnDataSource(data2)

    plot1 = figure(plot_width=850, plot_height=170, toolbar_location=None, active_drag=None, title="total")
    plot1.circle(x='missingnumber', y='holo', size=10, line_color='Blue', fill_color='DeepSkyBlue', alpha=0.5,
                 source=source1)

    plot2 = figure(plot_width=850, plot_height=170, toolbar_location=None, active_drag=None, title="test")
    plot2.circle(x='missingnumber', y='holo', size=10, line_color='Blue', fill_color='DeepSkyBlue', alpha=0.5,
                 source=source2)

    
    def callback1(plot2=plot2, source2=source2, window=None):
        
        inds = cb_data.source.selected['1d'].indices
        d1 = cb_data.source.attributes.data
        d2 = source2.data
        d2['time'] = []
        d2['projectname'] = []
        d2['id'] = []
        d2['missingnumber0'] = []
        d2['missingnumber1'] = []
        d2['missingnumber'] = []
        d2['holi'] = []
        d2['lilo'] = []
        d2['holo'] = []

        d2['time'].push(d1['time'][inds[0]])
        d2['projectname'].push(d1['projectname'][inds[0]])
        d2['id'].push(d1['id'][inds[0]])
        d2['missingnumber0'].push(d1['missingnumber0'][inds[0]])
        d2['missingnumber1'].push(d1['missingnumber1'][inds[0]])
        d2['missingnumber'].push(d1['missingnumber'][inds[0]])
        d2['holi'].push(d1['holi'][inds[0]])
        d2['lilo'].push(d1['lilo'][inds[0]])
        d2['holo'].push(d1['holo'][inds[0]])
        source2.change.emit()

    taptool1 = TapTool(callback=CustomJS.from_py_func(callback1))
    plot1.add_tools(taptool1)



    script2, div2 = components(plot1)
    script3, div3 = components(plot2)
   
    return render(request, 'test.html',
                  {'script2': script2, 'div2': div2, 'script3': script3, 'div3': div3})
```

I think the problem is that even though I change the source of the second plot , web browser does't send redraw command to this area . But I don't know how to fix this problem .